# Renaming file in bash script breaks the script

Tags: bash

Good day!  I have the following script which is supposed to rename and then send files in a folder on my Mac to an FTP server.

```
for f in "$@"
    do
        mv "$f" "${f%.mpeg}.mpg"
        curl -T "$f" ftp://1.2.3.4/Vol123456-01/MPEG/ --user me:secret
        mv "$f" "/Users/me/Sent Stuff"
    done
```

That works fine except for that first `mv` line.  The script successfully renames the file, but then the following commands seem to no longer be able to find `"$f"`.  I am pretty new to bash scripting.  Is there a way to refresh perhaps what `"$f"` means so that the `curl` and `mv` lines know what it is?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have nailed the problem exactly. The first `mv` renames the file. The original name `"$f"` no longer exists. Try this:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    g="${f%.mpeg}.mpg"
    mv "$f" "$g"
    curl -T "$g" ftp://1.2.3.4/Vol123456-01/MPEG/ --user me:secret
    mv "$g" "/Users/me/Sent Stuff"
done
```

Comment: That does it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could store the new name in another variable and then use that when you want to reach the file.

```
newname="${f%.mpeg}.mpg"
```

and then use the `"$newname"` for getting the variable.